# Redirect all website link www to non www and http to https using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When I go to `https://www.example.com/webinars.php`.

I want to be redirected to `https://example.com/webinars.php`
**But Its not working**.

My current `.htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi @Kashyap Dave, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question explains specifically what *should happen*, which is great. Could you also explain what *does happen*? What do the logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```